# read a data from kafka topic and aggregate using spark tempview?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, dataset

i want a read a data from kafka topic, and create spark tempview to group by some columns?

```
+----+--------------------+
| key|               value|          
+----+--------------------+
|null|{"e":"trade","E":...|
|null|{"e":"trade","E":...|
|null|{"e":"trade","E":...|
```

but i can't able to aggregate data from tempview?? value column data stored as a String???

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark
                  .readStream()
                  .format("kafka")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093")
                  .option("subscribe", "data2-topic")
                  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                  .option ("group.id", "test")
                  .option("enable.auto.commit", "true")
                  .option("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")          
                  .load();
          data.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");
          data.createOrReplaceTempView("Tempdata");
          data.show();
Dataset<Row> df2=spark.sql("SELECT e FROM Tempdata group by e");
df2.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> value column data stored as a String???

Yes.. Because you `CAST(value as STRING)`

You'll want to use a `from_json` function that'll load the row into a proper dataframe that you can search within.

See Databrick's blog on [Structured Streaming on Kafka](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html) for some examples

If the primary goal is just grouping of some fields, then KSQL might be an alternative.

Comment: How to aggregate the string values??

Comment: I cannot tell what data is in your topic, so hard to say. I would suggest getting the entire value dataframe first, though, rather than a string. If you have a new problem, best to create a new post for it